# Mailgun-js is throwing me a 301 error

Tags: node.js, mailgun

I'm building an email verification app and using Mailgun for the mail client, with mailgun-js.

I'm using this for my data:

```
{"from":"boris.kogan81@gmail.com",
"to":"boris.kogan81@gmail.com",
"subject":"Verify your email",
"text":"Hello,<br> Please click on the link to verify your email.<br><a href=https://mail-verification-baruchkogan.c9users.io/verify/borisbaruch kogan/Zr6expRlUhnKrXzBHg9X1gyT9laFSl1w91wrESv4B25tWnBDSphp8wKLTbeV4cFf>Click here to verify</a>"
}
```

And calling it with this function:

```
mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) { 
if(error) {console.log('mailgun error: ', error)} 
console.log(body); }
```

Which returns:

```
mailgun error: { [Error:

<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
301 Moved Permanently

nginx ] statusCode: 301 } undefined`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set `domain` in your `mailgun` initialization